Widget Color lightened
Why is my widget color not as per spec. It is appearing lightened. I have my scaffold color set as white.
              Container(
                height: 45,
                width: 272,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(66, 15, 129, 19),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(22),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 24,
                      width: 24,
                      child: Image(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/Google_logo.png'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        BlocProvider.of<AuthCubit>(context).loginWithGoogle();
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Log in with Google',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 45,
                width: 272,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(66, 76, 175, 79),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(22),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 24,
                        width: 24,
                        child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/Microsoft_logo.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          BlocProvider.of<AuthCubit>(context).loginWithMS();
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Log in with Microsoft',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 7,
              ),
              const Text(
                'OR',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 7),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 464, vertical: 0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          key: const ValueKey('email'),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                              return 'Please enter a valid email';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                            labelText: 'Email Address',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onSaved: (newValue) {
                            _userEmail = newValue!;
                          },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 12,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          key: const ValueKey('password'),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                              return 'Password must be atleast 7 characters';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                            labelText: 'Password',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                          ),
                          obscureText: true,
                          onSaved: (newValue) {
                            _userPassword = newValue!;
                          },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 2,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 45,
                width: 272,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: const ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                            Color.fromARGB(78, 2, 114, 6))),
                    onPressed: _trySubmit,
                    child: const Text(
                      'Log in',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.white),
                    )),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "Don't have an account yet?  ",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) => const RegistrationScreen()));
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Sign Up',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(85, 8, 95, 167),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )



The issue might be related to the alpha (transparency) value you're setting in your color.
You can try setting the alpha value to 255 for fully opaque colors:
color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 129, 19), 

Or you can directly use Color class constructors without specifying alpha like this way:
color: Color(0xFF0F8113), 

